# Is the use of "on" here correct?

Tags: grammar

> On meeting, he was upset and worried...

Is the use of ***on*** in this statement correct?

Answer (score 3):

OED gives the following relevant sense:

> 9. On the occasion of (an action); immediately after (and because of or in reaction to); as a result of; = upon prep. 7.

That fits your sentence just fine. The grammatical problem arises rather with the next two words. “On meeting” is a front-shifted modifier, and as such must modify *he,* the subject of the main clause; otherwise it is a [dangling modifier](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/dangling_modifiers_and_how_to_correct_them.html). Thus *he* must be the subject of the verb *to meet,* which remains a verb even in the gerund form *meeting.* Now, if the word were, say, *arriving,* that would be no problem; but the notion of just one person *meeting* is bound to strike many as odd.

As a commenter has pointed out, the problem could be solved by providing the verb *meeting* with a direct object:

> On meeting *the Estonian delegation,* he was upset and worried.

Comment: What is the _object_ of the verb _meeting_ here? It looks an incomplete, if a grammatical, sentence without specifying the object of _meeting._